# Два согласованных прилагательных после существительного - обособлять ли?

Tags: запятые, прилагательные

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со знаками препинания в поздравительном стихотворении.

> Пусть этот день(,) особый, женский(,) подарит Вам свое тепло.

Нужно ли выделять запятыми или лучше без них?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помнится, у Розенталя Д.Э. сказано, что обособляются два или более одиночных определений, стоящих после определяемого слова.Такие определения являются однородными, даже если характеризуют предмет с разных сторон. Еще большую уверенность в постановке запятых в Вашем случае придает наличие согласованного определения перед определяемым словом. Итак, у Вас все правильно написано